# Am I still a tenor?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, tenor

I'm only 16 and I recently found how to mix my head and chest registers.  I LOOOOOOVE singing in my passaggio, but it feels so unnecessary since it's so high, for a male anyway.  My full range goes from A2 to A5 and then pure head voice to Eb6. My passaggio starts at Bb4.

Am I still a tenor? Am I a Counter-tenor? A male mezzo-soprano? IDK at this point.

Comment: We get a lot of similar questions to this one, and I can't see a lot of point in asking them. At 16, there's a good chance your range will change in the next couple of years or so. Answers to questions such as this will have very little use for future readers.

Comment: It seems like you are confusing both 'passaggio' and 'head-voice' with **falsetto**...

Answer (score 4):

1) You will have more than one passaggi. The orientation of those passaggi will determine your fach, ultimately.
2) Physically speaking, you're still not 100% developed. If you're serious about becoming a classically trained, bel canto singer, you should be concentrating on developing your technique. I recommend reading a bit of Richard Miller ($20 tops), getting the Marchesi exercise manual ($10), and concentrating on breathing exercises and learning to correctly support initiation of tone (it's not as easy as it sounds, and it changes with age).

All that said, make sure to just enjoy it too. There's a lot of great rep out there for young tenors, so find a good teacher and dive in.